# Limit memory usage of Java 8 application (SceneBuilder)

Tags: memory, java

I'm experiencing trouble with (what appears to be) memory leaks in JavaFX Scene Builder. I have filed a bug report, but in the meantime my system sometimes gets unbearably slow as Scene Builder uses 10+ GB.

As a temporary fix I want to limit the amount of memory it can use. I have tried setting the following in SceneBuilder.cfg under JVMOptions:

```
-XX:InitialHeapSize=256m
-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

`jps` confirms the arguments are passed to the process:

```
3052  -Djava.library.path=/opt/SceneBuilder/app:/opt/SceneBuilder -Djava.launcher.path=/opt/SceneBuilder -Dapp.preferences.id=com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app -XX:InitialHeapSize=256m -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

However, the process still climbs up in memory usage, going way over 256MB, quickly surpassing 6GB and over.

So is there a way to truly limit the amount of memory used by a Java process?

Edit: I have tried using `ulimit`:

```
ulimit -d 1024000 -v 1024000 -m 1024000
```

but then I'm getting an error when trying to launch:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not allocate metaspace: 1073741824 bytes
```

which suggests Java indeed ignores the MetaspaceSize parameter. Any other way to limit memory in Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You're on Unix-based operating system.

1. You can run the program as different user and enforce limits defined in `/etc/security/limits.conf` on this account. This should also allow you to reserve more resources for your normal user account.
2. You can try caging the process with tool like [timeout](https://github.com/pshved/timeout).

But since ulimit doesn't help, it'll probably end up just with the process crashing (with cannot allocate memory) or being killed by the system.

Also check-out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process since this is similar question.

Edit: As for metaspace limit being ignored. Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075761/java-8-reserves-minimum-1g-for-metaspace-despite-maxmetaspacesize